# Sort String Value for Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have an issue as I am trying to select Date values stored in SQL server as String value with this format "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 06:08:20 -0700" and i need to select all table with newest date in first but  I do not know how to convert this String into Date and sort it. Thanks in advance.

Table

```
           |Thu, 08 Jul 2021 06:08:20 -0700|
           |Fri, 09 Jul 2021 01:08:20 -0700|
           |Sun, 11 Jul 2021 07:08:20 -0700|
```

output (Newest Date first)

```
           |Sun, 11 Jul 2021 07:08:20 -0700|
           |Fri, 09 Jul 2021 01:08:20 -0700|
           |Thu, 08 Jul 2021 06:08:20 -0700|
```

Comment: I couldn't even parsing working with `TRY_CONVERT`.  You should stop storing your dates as strings.

Comment: i will try to sort this values as a date but i also do not know if i can insert this format with convert or without convert and if i need to convert i do not know the format

Comment: You can't use `CONVERT` as far as I know.

Comment: okay thanks for your support and you comment and i will wait hopping that some one face this issue before and can solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is just missing a valid timezone offset value so needs a ":" inserted so it's `-07:00`, you can do this with `stuff` and use `substring` to ignore the irrelevant day name. You don't state a specific database platform, for SQL Server you can then cast to a `datetimeoffset`, other databases have similar but slightly varied syntax. This assumes the strings are all formatted consistently of course.

```
declare @d varchar(30)='Thu, 08 Jul 2021 06:08:20 -0700'
select Cast(Stuff(Substring(@d,6,26),25,0,':') as datetimeoffset(0))
```

Result

> 2021-07-08 06:08:20 -07:00

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need to know how to select the whole table and sort the result with the date sorted with this format "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 06:08:20 -0700"

Comment: Ok so ideally you would store the data as an actual `date` data type, however you can simply apply the cast in the `order by` - so for example `select * from table order by Cast(Stuff(Substring(DateColumnName,6,26),25,0,':') as datetimeoffset(0))`